# How do you link an HTML form to a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function

I have to make a calculation with Celsius (C) and Fahrenheit (F), and I think the form action line is wrong. How can I fix it?

Here is my HTML:

```html
<form action="javascript.html">
    Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit:<br>
    <input type="text" name="converterCtoF"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here is my JavaScript code:

```javascript
function tempertureConverter(C) {
    return (9/5)*C + 32;
}
```

What about the other way as well? Converting F to C.

Comment: You might want to check the solution at:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be posting to a different file with your form, but since you didn't specify the mark-up for the page you are posting to, here is a solution that will display the Fahrenheit on the current page.

```html
<script>
    function tempertureConverter(){
        var C = document.getElementById("degree").value;
        alert((9/5)*C+32);
    }
</script>

<form>
    Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit:<br>
    <input type="text" name="converterCtoF" id = "degree"><br>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id = "submit"
           onClick = "tempertureConverter()">
</form>
```

The above grabs the Celsius value the user inputs and runs the conversion function on it.  The result is then displayed as a pop-up in the browser.

A working example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RPG5m/).

Answer (score 2):

Is this [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F3J52/) what you had in mind? It listens for the form submission and calculates the Fahrenheit from the Celsius text field. This would all be on one page.

HTML:

```html
<form name="temperature_form" action="">
    Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit:<br>
    <input type="text" name="converterCtoF" id="converterCtoF"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```javascript
document.forms["temperature_form"].onsubmit = function(){
    var c = document.getElementById("converterCtoF").value;
    var f = (9/5)*c + 32;
    alert(f);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to set the form action to your PHP script, not JavaScript.

```html
<form action="celsius.php" method="get">
    Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit:<br>
    <input type="text" name="converterCtoF"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then in celsius.php you can access to the text field value via $_GET['converterCtoF'].

Comment: How do I change to PHP script?

Comment: But this is a normal form submit, with a roundtrip to the server. Why can't it all run on the client side (in JavaScript)?

Answer (score 0):

You would not change a PHP script. You need to create one. In this example above ...

```html
<form action="celsius.php" method="get">
    Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit:<br>
    <input type="text" name="converterCtoF"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

You need to create a file named celcius.php and add something similar to:

```
<?php
  $c = $_GET['converterCtoF'];
  $f = convertTemp(c);

  echo(f);

  function convertTemp(temp) {
    return (9/5)*C + 32;
  }
?>
```